# Javascript: Group and nest a flat array of product option combinations

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a flat array of product option combinations like "Shirt Type", "Color" and "Size" that I want to transform into a grouped, nested list that can more easily be presented to a customer.

- Nesting can be *up to* levels deep (my example below shows 3 levels, but other items may just have 1 or 2).
- Product option objects in the flat array can appear in somewhat
  random order (i.e. t-shirts, then sweatshirts, then a t-shirt
  again).
- Not every value exists in every group (i.e. Size XL might appear *only*
  for White T-shirts).
- This example shows shirts, but the option types may be completely
  different for other items (i.e. "optionType1" might be "Frame Size")

Example of the combinations data I need to transform:

```
[
  {
    "skuid": "TSWHTM",
    "optionType1": "Shirt Type",
    "optionName1": "T-Shirt",
    "optionValue1": "TS",
    "optionType2": "Color",
    "optionName2": "White",
    "optionValue2": "WHT",
    "optionName3": "Size",
    "optionType3": "Medium",
    "optionValue3": "M"
  },
  {
    "skuid": "TSWHTL",
    "optionType1": "Shirt Type",
    "optionName1": "T-Shirt",
    "optionValue1": "TS",
    "optionType2": "Color",
    "optionName2": "White",
    "optionValue2": "WHT",
    "optionType3": "Size",
    "optionName3": "Large",
    "optionValue3": "L"
  },
  {
    "skuid": "TSBLKM",
    "optionType1": "Shirt Type",
    "optionName1": "T-Shirt",
    "optionValue1": "TS",
    "optionType2": "Color",
    "optionName2": "Black",
    "optionValue2": "BLK",
    "optionType3": "Size",
    "optionName3": "Medium",
    "optionValue3": "M"
  },
  {
    "skuid": "TSBLKL",
    "optionType1": "Shirt Type",
    "optionName1": "T-Shirt",
    "optionValue1": "TS",
    "optionType2": "Color",
    "optionName2": "Black",
    "optionValue2": "BLK",
    "optionType3": "Size",
    "optionName3": "Large",
    "optionValue3": "L"
  },
  {
    "skuid": "SSWHTM",
    "optionType1": "Shirt Type",
    "optionName1": "Sweatshirt",
    "optionValue1": "SS",
    "optionType2": "Color",
    "optionName2": "White",
    "optionValue2": "WHT",
    "optionType3": "Size",
    "optionName3": "Medium",
    "optionValue3": "M"
  },
  {
    "skuid": "SSWHTL",
    "optionType1": "Shirt Type",
    "optionName1": "Sweatshirt",
    "optionValue1": "SS",
    "optionType2": "Color",
    "optionName2": "White",
    "optionValue2": "WHT",
    "optionType3": "Size",
    "optionName3": "Large",
    "optionValue3": "L"
  },
  {
    "skuid": "SSBLKM",
    "optionType1": "Shirt Type",
    "optionName1": "Sweatshirt",
    "optionValue1": "SS",
    "optionType2": "Color",
    "optionName2": "Black",
    "optionValue2": "BLK",
    "optionType3": "Size",
    "optionName3": "Medium",
    "optionValue3": "M"
  },
  {
    "skuid": "TSWHTXL",             <-- CAN APPEAR OUT OF ORDER (UN-GROUPED WITH OTHER T-SHIRTS)
    "optionType1": "Shirt Type",
    "optionName1": "T-Shirt",
    "optionValue1": "TS",
    "optionType2": "Color",
    "optionName2": "White",
    "optionValue2": "WHT",
    "optionType3": "Size",
    "optionName3": "Extra Large",   <-- THIS SIZE ONLY AVAILABLE FOR T-SHIRT / WHITE
    "optionValue3": "XL"
  },  
  {
    "skuid": "SSBLKL",
    "optionType1": "Shirt Type",
    "optionName1": "Sweatshirt",
    "optionValue1": "SS",
    "optionType2": "Color",
    "optionName2": "Black",
    "optionValue2": "BLK",
    "optionType3": "Size",
    "optionName3": "Large",
    "optionValue3": "L"
  }
]
```

And here's an example of what it would be transformed into:

```
{
  "options": [
    {
      "optionType1": "Shirt Type",
      "optionName1": "T-Shirt",
      "optionValue1": "TS",
      "options": [
        {
          "optionType2": "Color",
          "optionName2": "White",
          "optionValue2": "WHT",
          "options": [
            {
              "optionType3": "Size",
              "optionName3": "Medium",
              "optionValue3": "M",
              "skuid": "TSWHTM"
            },
            {
              "optionType3": "Size",
              "optionName3": "Large",
              "optionValue3": "L",
              "skuid": "TSWHTL"
            },
            {
              "optionType3": "Size",
              "optionName3": "Extra Large",
              "optionValue3": "XL",
              "skuid": "TSWHTXL"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "optionType2": "Color",
          "optionName2": "Black",
          "optionValue2": "BLK",
          "options": [
            {
              "optionType3": "Size",
              "optionName3": "Medium",
              "optionValue3": "M",
              "skuid": "TSWHTM"
            },
            {
              "optionType3": "Size",
              "optionName3": "Large",
              "optionValue3": "L",
              "skuid": "TSWHTL"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "optionType1": "Shirt Type",
      "optionName1": "Sweatshirt",
      "optionValue1": "SS",
      "options": [
        {
          "optionType2": "Color",
          "optionName2": "White",
          "optionValue2": "WHT",
          "options": [
            {
              "optionType3": "Size",
              "optionName3": "Medium",
              "optionValue3": "M",
              "skuid": "SSWHTM"
            },
            {
              "optionType3": "Size",
              "optionName3": "Large",
              "optionValue3": "L",
              "skuid": "SSWHTL"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "optionType2": "Color",
          "optionName2": "Black",
          "optionValue2": "BLK",
          "options": [
            {
              "optionType3": "Size",
              "optionName3": "Medium",
              "optionValue3": "M",
              "skuid": "SSWHTM"
            },
            {
              "optionType3": "Size",
              "optionName3": "Large",
              "optionValue3": "L",
              "skuid": "SSWHTL"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I could then show "Shirt Type", "Color" and "Size" menus in the UI and update each menu when a selection is made (based on availability).

That's the model I've come up with in my head though I am not married to it, if anyone has any better modeling ideas.  I started writing the code that does the transform but it quickly turned to spaghetti, so I thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the data and use an object as result set.

Inside of the iteration, loop a counter for the option keys and check if the key exists in the actual object. If not create a new object and use this object for the next loop of the counter.

As result, you get an array of objects with nested arrays.

```js
var data = [{ skuid: "TSWHTM", optionType1: "Shirt Type", optionName1: "T-Shirt", optionValue1: "TS", optionType2: "Color", optionName2: "White", optionValue2: "WHT", optionName3: "Size", optionType3: "Medium", optionValue3: "M" }, { skuid: "TSWHTL", optionType1: "Shirt Type", optionName1: "T-Shirt", optionValue1: "TS", optionType2: "Color", optionName2: "White", optionValue2: "WHT", optionType3: "Size", optionName3: "Large", optionValue3: "L" }, { skuid: "TSBLKM", optionType1: "Shirt Type", optionName1: "T-Shirt", optionValue1: "TS", optionType2: "Color", optionName2: "Black", optionValue2: "BLK", optionType3: "Size", optionName3: "Medium", optionValue3: "M" }, { skuid: "TSBLKL", optionType1: "Shirt Type", optionName1: "T-Shirt", optionValue1: "TS", optionType2: "Color", optionName2: "Black", optionValue2: "BLK", optionType3: "Size", optionName3: "Large", optionValue3: "L" }, { skuid: "SSWHTM", optionType1: "Shirt Type", optionName1: "Sweatshirt", optionValue1: "SS", optionType2: "Color", optionName2: "White", optionValue2: "WHT", optionType3: "Size", optionName3: "Medium", optionValue3: "M" }, { skuid: "SSWHTL", optionType1: "Shirt Type", optionName1: "Sweatshirt", optionValue1: "SS", optionType2: "Color", optionName2: "White", optionValue2: "WHT", optionType3: "Size", optionName3: "Large", optionValue3: "L" }, { skuid: "SSBLKM", optionType1: "Shirt Type", optionName1: "Sweatshirt", optionValue1: "SS", optionType2: "Color", optionName2: "Black", optionValue2: "BLK", optionType3: "Size", optionName3: "Medium", optionValue3: "M" }, { skuid: "TSWHTXL", optionType1: "Shirt Type", optionName1: "T-Shirt", optionValue1: "TS", optionType2: "Color", optionName2: "White", optionValue2: "WHT", optionType3: "Size", optionName3: "Extra Large", optionValue3: "XL" }, { skuid: "SSBLKL", optionType1: "Shirt Type", optionName1: "Sweatshirt", optionValue1: "SS", optionType2: "Color", optionName2: "Black", optionValue2: "BLK", optionType3: "Size", optionName3: "Large", optionValue3: "L" }],
    keys = ['optionType', 'optionName', 'optionValue'],
    result = data
        .reduce((r, o) => {
            var t = r;

            for (let i = 1, key = 'optionValue' + i; key in o; key = 'optionValue' + ++i) {
                let item = (t.option = t.option || []).find(q => q[key] === o[key]);
                if (!item) t.option.push(item = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k + i, o[k + i]])));
                t = item;
            }
            t.skuid = o.skuid;

            return r;
        }, { option: [] })
        .option;    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow, magic!  Thank you, Nina!